# How I make multiple webservices sharing a common XSD in Microsoft AX 2012?

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a Microsoft AX 2012 which spawn miultiple services (called for this question service1, service2 and service3).

each of these webservices generatewsdl for the allowed operation and xsd for the data (de)serialized.

The code behind them use a common set of DataContract. The problem I have is that each of the wsdl point to one different XSD defining these contract. Even if the content and the namespace is exactly the same, the URI is different :

- http:////service1/xppservice?xsd=xsd1
- http:////service2/xppservice?xsd=xsd1
- http:////service3/xppservice?xsd=xsd1
- and so on...

Is there a way to allow the generated wsdl to point at the same XSD file ?

EDIT :

We ended by creating a service group, regrouping all the service. Each one is correponding to a HttpBinding, and all the services are sharing the same XSD

Comment: Did you add all services to the same service group or integration port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Each Web Service has different data structures and operations (there's no much sense in creating two WS with the same data and operations), and it's supposed to service an entire area of funcionality. Ax creates a WSDL and a XSD to each Integration port you create.

So, if you need service1, service2, etc to use same XSS, you must deactivate it and put in all operations you need to use same XSD (and will use same WSDL), and perhaps you will need to group all WS services in a same service group before selecting operations in WS integration port.

Comment: The point is, the webservices use the same data, but do not provide the same operations. So we need some separation on the last point. But we are investigating the possibility to provide multiple binding port in the same service